# Moment of inertia for hollow and solid tori.

Tags: calculus

Does the  centroid of a curve determine its moment of inertia of hollow or solid torus section rotated about its symmetry axis in a manner quite similar to application of Pappu's theorems (when calculating surface area/volume)? Here in addition we take areas or masses into consideration.

EDIT1:

In mechanics of materials for area moments of inertia

Areal Moment of inertia of hollow torus =
$\text{distance}^2$ traveled by centroid of region $\cdot \text{Area} $

Areal Moment of inertia of solid torus =
 $\text{distance}^2$ traveled by centroid of region $\cdot\text{Volume} $

and for mass moment of inertia in dynamics we should have

Mass Moment of inertia of hollow torus =
radius^2  centroid of region $ \cdot q \cdot Area_{Pappu} $

Mass Moment of inertia of solid torus =
radius^2 centroid of region $ \cdot \gamma \cdot {Volume_{Pappu} } $

where $q, \gamma $ are areal and volume densities respectively.

Are these correct? If not how may be the integrals expressed?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot be correct, just from dimensional analysis. Moment of inertia has units of mass times distance squared. Your two formulas have units of distance to the fourth and fifth power

Comment: There is an area moment of inertia also (mechanics). Shall edit it

Comment: Good point, @Andrei, but maybe it would be best to post as a comment.

Comment: Moment of inertia is sometimes reported on a volume basis instead of a mass basis, in which case you would recover the mass-based moment of inertia by multiplying by the density. For a three-dimensional solid we would expect the volune-based quantity to have units of length to the fifth power.